# Is there a specific name for this style of UI?

Tags: gui-design, terminology

Most of the Microsoft Office 2013 programs I use have a similar style UI with the 'Ribbon' at the top like this:
[image]

I recently started using ArcGIS Pro and noticed it uses the same style UI (screenshot below), is there an industry standard term for this style of UI that I can use to describe the look to a user:
[image]

I realize many types of software have a similar style UI but I am referring in particular to how its ribbon is almost identical to Microsoft programs.

Comment: You used the name twice yourself. It's called a [ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_%28computing%29). Microsoft's particular implementation is the [Windows Ribbon Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371191(v=vs.85).aspx) ([Ribbons UI Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742393.aspx)).

Comment: I have some names for that interface...

Comment: @MattObee I was just unsure if there was a more specific term for the Microsoft style ribbon +1 for the WRF link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface element is called a ribbon.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing)

Since Microsoft popularized the term, the Microsoft ribbon is the canonical example of this interface type.

If you need to refer specifically to the Microsoft style of ribbon I have not heard designers use any term other than "the Office [insert specific version] ribbon".  I don't  think it's deserving of any more specific descriptors than that.

This is a controversial interface, to say the least.